# Make Django migrations to cloud sql private instance using code from Github

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am able to create triggers in cloud-build for development environment where my cloud sql is public.
But in production env where cloud sql is private, I am unable to make django migrations because cloud build does not support VPC.

Comment: You should be able to assign IAM permissions to your cloud build default role to allow permissions to connect and interact with Cloud SQL. I would focus on IAM before getting tangled with VPC.

Comment: My cloud build sv account has cloud sql admin role assigned

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: There's already an [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/123374893) to support VPC on Cloud Build. Please make sure to "star" the issue so it can gain traction. The [feature](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/supported-products#table_build) is currently on ["preview"](https://cloud.google.com/products#section-22)

Comment: @Dondi - is there a workaround that you currently use? like using a CE or Cloud run to pull data from github and make migrations to private cloud sql? If yes, is there a detailed public doc that you have or can you detail those steps here please.